# Print: Div side by side

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I need your help. I have a form that have 2 div side by side (on the left & right), as 2 columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="printable">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form role="form"></form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form role="form"></form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have two javascript to print those div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv_1(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}

function PrintDiv_2() {
    var divContents = document.getElementById("printdivcontent").innerHTML;
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=200,width=400');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print DIV Content</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write(divContents);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
}
```

but the result **in the pdf file** format always sequence, from top to down of the page. It becomes 2 rows.

how to overcome this issue ?
I think, there are something in the javascript that I miss.

Thank in Adv.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row" id="printable">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form role="form"></form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form role="form"></form>
    </div>

</div>
```

If you make a column (col-lg-12) after the row class, the row becomes useless.

Comment: does it really matter ? I get example from this [link](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/grid.html), Nesting columns. And, it works fine

Comment: Actually, in the html, it's already appear 2 column (1 row) but, again in format pdf, it becomes 1 column and 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `col-lg-12`
As its equivalent to BootStrap row size.
All colomn class like

> `col-md-12  , col-sm-12, col-xs-12`

All of these will act same way on different size.

And don't forget, if you want to have some elements in one row, make the total count equal to `12`

For example,

> `col-md-6 and col-md-6`
>
> `col-md-4 and col-md-8`

So, the total sum of two `col-*-*` is 12, and they will stay side by side.

**If the elements sum is more than 12, the later element will go right below the first element**

Comment: yeah, I'm agree with your answer. But, in pdf format it becomes 2 row and 1 columns. Any idea with this ?

Comment: I think its the same reason. When first row is filled up the following element goes to new row [no matter how many content it contains]